# Kendo UI AutoComplete (MVC) MinLength reloads all values

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-autocomplete

I have a Kendo UI autocomplete using the MVC helper:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m => m)
     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("CustomerNames_Read", "Wells")))
     .DataTextField("Name")
     .MinLength(3))
```

The MinLength works fine, only retrieving values when 3 letters are entered.

The problem is if you clear the box it retrieves all values (which in this instance is 1000+). How can I stop this?

The same behavior can be seen in the demo:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/index

Enter a letter, such as 'b', then delete it - all values are retrieved.

Comment: I never found a solution for this @gsharp! I'll see if I can get help from Telerik - I need it fixed!

Comment: ok. let me know if they give you a good answer. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I've raised a support ticket at Telerik. The answer was that this is apparently by design because [customers wanted it that way](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/574).

This can be prevented by implementing some JavaScript client side (see [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/#@c0re/uToPa/3))

Since I'm not so happy whit the JavaScript approach I've raised a feature request, that extends the MinLenght like this

```
.MinLength(int length, bool triggerOnEmptyText = true)
```

not sure if it's going to be implemented yet, will update as soon as I get an answer.

**UPDATE:**

Got feedback from Telerik. They won't implement it unless it geht a high vot in the User Voice.
So if you like the Feature pleae vote [here](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-telerik-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/8278863-extend-autocomplete-with-a-customizable-option-to)!